# JOIN ON syntax error in Microsoft Access 2016

Tags: ms-access, syntax, ms-access-2016

I am querying a couple tables, and for some reason Microsoft Access 2016 continually informed me that my SQL query `JOIN ON` syntax is incorrect. Specifically, the `JOIN` syntax is highlighted, followed by the `ON` syntax when removing that (the latter for clearer reasons based on prior knowledge of SQL `JOIN ON` syntax).

Here is the code:

```
SELECT Column1, Column2, Table1.Column3
FROM Table1 
JOIN Table2
    ON Table1.Column3 = Table2.Column3
   AND Column4 = '{NAME}'
ORDER BY Column4;
```

Is there something incorrect about this syntax? By the way, this is using ANSI-89 Syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I realized needed the `INNER JOIN` syntax rather than `JOIN ON` syntax for Access 2016 as `JOIN ON` without a combination of `INNER JOIN`, `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, `RIGHT OUTER JOIN`, etc. does not work with this DBMS (Database Management System). Further, I changed the `AND` logical operator to a `WHERE` clause as `JOIN ON` syntax followed simply by `AND` does not run in Access 2016. Furthermore, the `GROUP BY` syntax goes beyond the minimum requirements for this query, so I removed it. Therefore, the solution to my question is as follows:

```
SELECT Column1, Column2, Table1.Column3

FROM Table1 

INNER JOIN Table2

ON Table1.Column3 = Table2.Column3

WHERE Column4 = '{NAME}';
```

Comment: I think you are wrong about the `AND` part. I think Access allows `ON (condition` AND condition2)`. It may need parentheses though.

Comment: Your proposal is syntactically different than mine was because the code after the `ON` of the `INNER JOIN` syntax would be considered a single statement. Your code suggestion works equivalently, but the `AND` in my original code was after the `INNER JOIN ON` syntax. `AND` being a logical operator works between two data entries. Therefore, as I understand it, saying `AND` at the beginning of a SQL statement is syntactically incorrect. Hence, my original code would not run even with `INNER JOIN`

Comment: It certainly would not run if you didn't try it. If you tried it, it would run ;)

Comment: I think that is missing the point of my response in that your suggestion did not apply to the context of my requirements. Whether it worked is not as important as its relevance to the SQL requirement at that time.

Answer (score 2):

Access requires `INNER JOIN`. The simple `JOIN` (which should default to `INNER JOIN` according to the SQL standard) is not allowed in Access.

Answer (score -2):

After this passage `ON Table1.Column3 = Table2.Column3` you should put `where` instead of `and`.

Comment: You are correct. I did that as well. Having said that, the JOIN ON syntax does not run without the INNER syntax